# Preview CKEditor toolbar in settings disappear (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I think that since i added some new plugins for ckeditor (in drupal 7), the toolbar preview apperance which is in settings is gone .
There is a picture to explain:

[image]

In the "current toolbar" should be the toolbar and with the section under, i can normally just drag and drop some new buttons for this toolbar.

If someone have any idea to fix this as it as to be, it would be awesome.

Thanks, have a good day.

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is that you open browser console (F12) and see if there are any JavaScript errors being thrown. Most likely one of those new plugins is conflicting with existing toolbar feature (perhaps it is missing something that toolbar feature requires). You might also want to check Drupal logs if the error gets thrown in server-side code. Perhaps knowing the error will point you to the right direction although the simplest solution would probably be removing the problematic plugin.

Comment: @j.swiderski good idea, i'll check thank you !